# Hibernate @NotEmpty annotation equivalent in Javax.package or alternative

Tags: java, validation, annotations, bean-validation, notnull

Is there a way to implement `@NotEmpty` hibernate validation without writing custom validation?
javax.validation package does not contain this annotation. Only `@NotNull`. But it does not validate for Non-null but empty values. So I would like to see an alternative for `@NotEmpty`.

Using `@Pattern`? How?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

NotEmpty is just a combination of `@NotNull` and `@Size(min=1)`.

Comment: Does `@Size(min=1)` subsume `@NotNull`? e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/javax/validation/constraints/Size.java

Comment: @SK9 comment from the javadoc on the file you linked: "null elements are considered valid."

Comment: It is not exact the same - such combination will not work for just blank characters while @NoteEmpty will.

Comment: @aleksjej you are thinking of `@NotBlank`.  the source of `@NotEmpty` is merely: `@NotNull
@Size(min = 1)
public @interface NotEmpty {`

Answer (score 9):

Please be aware that @NotEmpty will return valid for a List<> containing a null element.

Kind of bizarre in the case of a @QueryParam List<>

As say Affe, I did a custom annotation, itself annotated with @NotNull and @Size(min=1) with a custom validator that iterates the collection and positions a boolean flag only if the elements are not null.

Answer (score 2):

In the Hibernate `@NotEmpty` source code after Hibernate 6, it told us use the standard `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` constraint instead:

```
/**
 * Asserts that the annotated string, collection, map or array is not {@code null} or empty.
 *
 * @author Emmanuel Bernard
 * @author Hardy Ferentschik
 *
 * @deprecated use the standard {@link javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty} constraint instead
 */
```

See: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/6.0/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.java

This new annotation comes from Bean Validation 2.0 (JSR 380).  See:

- http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#builtinconstraints-notempty
- https://github.com/beanvalidation/beanvalidation-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/validation/constraints/NotEmpty.java

Comment: @NotEmpty returns a valild list with o element

Comment: @TayabHussain What `@NotEmpty`? Hibernate `@NotEmpty` or Bean Validation spec `@NotEmpty`? The Bean Validation spec `@NotEmpty` can validate string, collection, map or array too as the source code and Hibernate team point out.

Answer (score 1):

For Hibernate it is deprecated in the newer version.
With the newer version of Javax validation it has `@Empty`

Use

`import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;`

```
@NotEmpty
private List<Record> records;
```